# Based on first spinner how to get second spinner and third spinner data

Tags: android

from JSON I got server side respose.and i set data to spinners also.but based on first spinner items position i have to get the details of second spinner and based on second spinner i have to get details of third spinner.can anyone plz read the code  and send me response 
Thank You.....

```
public class Send extends Fragment {

  Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
  Button b1, b2;
  Bitmap bmp;
  String image;
  int category_id;
  ImageView iview;
  Intent i = new Intent();

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send, container, false);
    sp1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.categories);
    sp2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.selectCity);
    sp3 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.selectArea);
    b1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.search);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName(getActivity(), Image.class));
        i.putExtra("image", image);
        startActivity(i);
      }
    });
    b2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
    new City().execute();
    new Area().execute();
    /* new MyTask().execute(); */
    return v;
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String msg = "";
    URL url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
        /*
         * URL url = new URL(
         * "http://creersoft.com/webservices/StoreService.php?categories="
         * +
         * sp1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"&city="+sp2.getSelectedItem
         * ().toString()+"&area="+sp3.getSelectedItem().toString());
         */
        url = new URL(
            "http://creersoft.com/webservices/StoreService.php?categories="
                + sp1.getSelectedItem().toString() + "&city="
                + sp2.getSelectedItem().toString() + "&area="
                + sp3.getSelectedItem().toString());

        InputStream isr = url.openStream();
        int i = isr.read();

        while (i != -1) {
          msg = msg + (char) i;
          i = isr.read();
        }

      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      try {
        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(msg);

        JSONArray jsonArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("Result");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject subObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          image = subObject.getString("image");

          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();

          int id = subObject.getInt("id");
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          String storename = subObject.getString("storename");
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), storename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();
        }

      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  // Download JSON file AsyncTask
  private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ArrayList<String> worldlist;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> world;

    /*
     * ArrayList<String> listnew; ArrayList<String> sp;
     */

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPreExecute();

      pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
      pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
      pDialog.setCancelable(false);
      pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // Locate the WorldPopulation Class
      world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();

      worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();

      jsonobject = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://creersoft.com/webservices/getcategory.php");

      try {
        JSONObject maJsonObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("Response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = maJsonObject.getJSONArray("Result");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           category_id=jsonobject.getInt("id");
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), category_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               

          WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

          worldpop.setId(jsonobject.optInt("id"));
          worldpop.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));

          world.add(worldpop);

          // Populate spinner with country names
          worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));

        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
      // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
      if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();

      sp1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, worldlist));          
    }
  }

  class City extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<String> worldlist;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> world;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPreExecute();
      pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
      pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Cities information..");
      pDialog.setCancelable(false);
      pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
      worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
      jsonobject = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://creersoft.com/webservices/getcity.php?category_id="+category_id);
      try {
        JSONObject maJsonObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("Response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = maJsonObject.getJSONArray("Result");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

          WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();
          worldpop.setName(jsonobject.optString("city"));

          world.add(worldpop);
          worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("city"));
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
      sp2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, worldlist));
    }
  }

  class Area extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<String> worldlist;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> world;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPreExecute();
      pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
      pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Areas Information..");
      pDialog.setCancelable(false);
      pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
      worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
      jsonobject = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://creersoft.com/webservices/getarea.php?category_id="+category_id+"&city_id=Lagos");
      try {
        JSONObject maJsonObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("Response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = maJsonObject.getJSONArray("Result");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

          WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();
          worldpop.setName(jsonobject.optString("area"));

          world.add(worldpop);
          worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("area"));

        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
      sp3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, worldlist));
    }
  }      
}
```

Here is my JSON Response for all theree spinners:

```
Spinner1:{"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"id":"1","name":"Groceries &   Convenience"},{"id":"2","name":"Pharmacy "},{"id":"3","name":"Fashion & Accessories"},{"id":"4","name":"Electronics"},{"id":"5","name":"Beauty & Wellness"},{"id":"6","name":"Food"},{"id":"7","name":"Books & Games"},{"id":"8","name":"For Kids"},{"id":"9","name":"Home & Living"},{"id":"10","name":"Travel & Hotels"}]}}spinner2:{"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"city":"Kano"},{"city":"Lagos"}]}}spinner3:-{"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"area":"Lekki"}]}}
```

Comment: use setOnItemSelectedListener. First load values of first spinner . Then in onitemSelected of 2nd spinner you will get pos selected of 1st spinner according to that pos call wedservice for loading values of 2nd spinner and similarly in onitemSelected of 2nd spinner you can call webservice to get values of 3rd spinner

Comment: Thanks for  reply user2564055. I tried setOnItemSelected but i didn't get output.can anyone give suggestion other than this.

Comment: user2564055 can you please show me that what you tell in practical way

Answer (score 0):

You can use setOnItemSelectedListener()

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.i("Selected item : ", items);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search about  `View.performClick()`. I think it will solve your problem.

On loading of first `spinner` data,  save position in temporary variable and call `performclick()` for next button and so-on.

Comment: anddevmanu i tried this one also but still i didn't get output.can you plz send me code briefly regarding about this.

Comment: First tell me all your task is independent , you are calling all tasks in oncreate() method. But i think every task is dependent on other, so call second task on calling of onPostExecute() of first .

Comment: if i am giving in async task in  onpostexectute of categories i got null pointer exception.

Comment: looking at your code you are giving wrong category_id and city_id , it is not dynamic , i think city_id and category_id will come after the spinner selection.
 jsonobject = JSONfunctions
          .getJSONfromURL("http://creersoft.com/webservices/getarea.php?category_id="+category_id+"&city_id=Lagos");